# how to make one way glass

Tags: transparency, glass

I'm trying to make one-way glass like the one used in interrogation rooms. if you look at it from one side, it's a solid color and from the other it's clear glass, so only one side can see the other.
Is there a way to do so in blender?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Geometry* node and its *Backfacing* output as factor in a *Mix Shader*:

[image]

[image]

If you are in Eevee don't forget to enable the *Alpha Blend* option to have transparency:

[image]

If you give it thickness, select one face and invert it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> *> Flip*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: of course it can be a bit more complicated setup than just transparency (Glass, Glossy, etc)

Comment: is there a way to do it if I wanted to add thickness instead of just a plane

Comment: I've edited, if you are in Eevee don't forget to enable Alpha Blend

Comment: If you give it thickness, select one face and invert it with Alt N > Flip

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140752/discussion-between-moonboots-and-jo-xxx).